# Windows 7 Backup not backing up custom library?

Tags: windows-7, backup, troubleshooting, restore

I have created a custom Library under Windows 7 64bit professional to handle my source code. When I tried Windows Backup and Restore for the first time I get the following error

> Backup encountered a problem while backing up file C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Source. Error:(The system cannot find the file specified. (0x80070002))

I've found a thread on the error on the [Microsoft answers site](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7repair/thread/803aacf5-b807-47a7-9209-b1323cad4e1f). But it appears to be 404 (there is a [version in Google's Cache](http://74.125.93.132/search?q=cache:Bp6Dde1o-tIJ:social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7repair/thread/803aacf5-b807-47a7-9209-b1323cad4e1f+windows+backup+not+backing+up+custom+library&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)) and the thread starter never gets an answer to his issue that works.

The [official Microsoft answer](http://blogs.technet.com/filecab/archive/2008/03/12/common-causes-and-solutions-to-backup-system-restore-and-complete-pc-backup-problems-updated.aspx) on this is

> This problem is due to one or more profiles under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList with missing ProfileImagePath.
>
> To check whether you have missing profiles:
>
> 1. Open regedit, navigate to the above registry key. (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList). Expand the list
> 2. Click on each of the profiles listed. The first 3 profiles should have ProfileImagePath value of
>      %SystemRoot%\System32\Config\SystemProfile, %SystemRoot%\ServiceProfiles\LocalService, and %SystemRoot%\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService respectively.
> 3. Starting from the 4th profile, the ProfileImagePath should contain path to the user profiles on your machine, such as C:\users\Christine
> 4. If one or more of the profile has no profile image, then you have missing profiles.
>
> To work around this, delete the profile in question (Caution: The registry contains critical settings that are necessary for your system to function properly. Take extra caution while making changes)
>
> 1. First, export the ProfileList key for safekeeping. (Right click on the key, choose “Export”, and save it to the desktop.)
> 2. Right click on the profile in question, choose delete.
> 3. Try backup again.

This **does not** work for me.

Anyone have any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, has anyone successfully backed up custom libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [KB979281](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/979281/error-code-0x8100002f-and-or-error-code-0x80070002-when-you-back-up-files-in-windows-7), this should explain what's happening and how to resolve it.

> This issue occurs if you back up a library that contains custom
>   folders that are located under your user profile.
>
> To resolve this issue, take one of the following actions:
>
> 1. Move the library folder from the
>      user profile path to a location outside the user profile path. For
>      example, move the folder to the C:\MyLibraries folder.
> 2. Exclude the library from the list of files that Windows Backup backs up.
>      Then include the original location of the content in the library in the
>      backup list.
> 3. Move the library folder to a location other than the user
>      profile folder. Then, add a link to the moved folder from the library.
>      Make sure that the library is included in the backup.

Comment: thanks. The scenorio 1 resolution seems to be what I was looking for. Can you post the text from the resolution into this answer, just in case Microsoft removes or moves the article? I would edit it myself but my rep isn't high enough.

Comment: -1 Because the answer is a link to the answer.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a really old thread but, since it's just solved my problem, thought I'd update.
I followed Solution 1 linked above. It was dead easy:

- Create a folder in C:\ called MyLibraries
- Locate problem library under your profile (or click Start to find it, as described)
- Drag library to new MyLibraries folder.

That's it! I was all ready to reset my library link to the new location, but found Windows had already done it. Hurrah.

Answer (score 1):

This thread discusses the problem : [RC backup error 0x80070002](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprogeneral/thread/52d70cd1-5ddb-4b85-9099-fdef5aae0102).

An official Microsoft answer is included towards the end by "Sneha [MSFT]", but I would suggest reading the entire thread.

However, one of the participants has solved his problem by **creating** the named file, which is apparently a bad profile name that was defined in some unknown way. So better check if this file does exist on your computer.

Comment: Yeah the advice there is to exclude the custom library from the backup and backup the actual paths. That workaround had occurred to me, and I may use it if I can't get it working any other way, but it pretty much defeats the purpose of libraries.

Comment: The libraries *idea* is great, but they're nothing but trouble when you're trying to do backups. I had to use the literal paths to do backups because I have network locations in my libraries, and Windows stupidly tries to back those up too and obviously can't.